# Understanding the job request returned information

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've created the function, which returns JobRequests of agents' jobs through Rest API.
I wonder about some jobs on one agent, which are started at one time but mapped every time to different builds (and when I click on this job in Azure DevOps Web UI - I've got "Build is not found".

[image]

I’ve noticed, that all these job requests have the next same parameters:

```
serviceOwner    : 00025394-6065-48ca-87d9-7f5672854ef7
hostId          : ffaea179-06ce-45ea-afcd-fde8cd8d156f
scopeId         : 6a21ca14-654d-492e-8c3b-83fa3a910dc6
```

May somebody explain what do these parameters mean (or point to the documentation link, where it is explained).
And how can I get the real Azure DevOps objects using these IDs?

Thank You!